# How can I write hex to binary in binary file as word(not byte)?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert word of hex to binary file.
for example,
0xffff to binary

I check it with hexdump -C filename

```
newFileBytes = [123041, 3, 255, 0, 100] 
newFile = open("f.bin", "wb") 
for byte in newFileBytes:
newFile.write(byte.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) 
newFile.close()
```

I get an exception because of 123041 , that is word , not byte:
OverflowError: int too big to convert

Comment: Please ask your question in detail and give an example of what you want to do/get.

Comment: I want to create binary file @DivyangVashi

Comment: Sure... but obviously you need to write it as N many bytes to represent that number... Are you ever wanting to read them back as you won't have anyway of getting 123041 back out without further meta data...